# SSRS: URL Encoding in Report Services

Tags: sql, url, reporting-services, encoding, system.web

I am trying to deploy a report and I added the following to the Report Properties:

```
System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a.
```

I am getting the following error message:

> "Error    1   Error while loading code module: ‘System.Web,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a’.
>   Details: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its
>   dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.      0   0   "

I am running SQL Server 2012, Report Builder 3.0 and SQL Server Visual Studio 2010.  I have copied System.Web to several locations on my C:\ drive, but am still getting the deploy error.

What is the correct folder System.Web.dll should reside?

Answer (score 0):

did you add the assembly through report designer in Visual Studio? Report -> Report Properties -> References then click Add on Add or remove assemblies...